# How can I cut a very long Doctrine annotation?

Tags: php, annotations, doctrine-orm

I have a 216 column annotation, that's hard to read and is not nice at all.

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="tree", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_u", columns={"name"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="userid_i", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="children_i", columns={"children"})})
```

Do you know a way to break it without killing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who come here, this way worked :

```
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="tree",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_u", columns={"name"})},
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="userid_i", columns={"user_id"}),
 *          @ORM\Index(name="children_i", columns={"children"})
 *      }
 * )
```